# How to push mule(Java based) logs to Prometheus storage?

Tags: grafana, prometheus, nagios, splunk, telegraf

I have a mule application which mostly does HTTP requests, which is logging as plain text. I want to push these logs as metrics to Prometheus. Since this is a legacy application it would take a substantial amount of time to change code and push metrics directly into Prometheus storage.

Idea is to show Prometheus metrics in Grafana Dashboard.

Is there any intermediate tool that converts plain text to metrics?

Anything that helps with this requirement.

FYI- We have Nagios and Splunk which is doing this task as of now, we are looking to move our solution to Prometheus and Grafana

Comment: Good starting point is using something like this: https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/tree/master/text_collector_examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like these you can use tools like https://github.com/fstab/grok_exporter to convert logs into metrics.